# Downloading .tar causes loop

Tags: php, fopen, tar

I'm trying to 1-click tar a directory and prompt a download of the tar.gz. I have another page that I select the directory to tar, but now when I download it I can't open it. It just expands the .tar to a .cpgz then back to the .tar and on and on.

```
<?php
require_once('header.html');
ini_set('max_execution_time','0');

if (isset($_POST)) {
    $site = $_POST['site'][0];
    if(empty($site)) {
        echo("<p class=\"text-danger\"><strong>You didn't select anything to tar.</strong></p>");
    } else {
            $site_name = str_replace('.', '' , $site);
    $command = "/bin/tar --strip-components=2 -czvf /var/www/backup/" . date("ymd") . "_${site_name}.tar.gz /var/www/${site}";
            shell_exec($command);
            $pathtofile = "/var/www/backup/" . date("ymd") . "_${site_name}.tar.gz";
            $filename = date("ymd") . "_${site_name}.tar.gz";

            function promptToDownload($path, $browserFilename, $mimeType)
            {
                    if (!file_exists($path) || !is_readable($path)) {
                            return null;
                    }

                    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/x-gzip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($browserFilename).'"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($browserFilename));

                    $fp = fopen($path, "r");
                    fpassthru($fp);
            }

            promptToDownload($pathtofile, $filename, 'multipart/x-gzip');
    }
}

require_once('footer.html');

?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There are missing parts of your code.

Comment: Can you help me understand where? This assumes that the file is already on the server in a specific directory. This should just prompt you do download that file.

Comment: `/var/www/${sit$`, have a look at your initial question.

Comment: I've repasted the code. I also changed the headers (thought that was the issue). The download is still not working as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [questions/3403795/headers-to-force-the-download-of-a-tar-archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403795/headers-to-force-the-download-of-a-tar-archive).